# how to add setonclickListener to listview in android widgets

Tags: android, android-widget

i am creating simple application in android to show all products in widget. if i click on one item in list view, just open a activity or show a toast message in android.
please help me i am new in android.

```
public class WidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

    /* 
     * this method is called every 30 mins as specified on widgetinfo.xml
     * this method is also called on every phone reboot
     */
    private static final String MyOnClick1 = "myOnClickTag1";
    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
            int[] appWidgetIds) {
        final int N = appWidgetIds.length;
        /*int[] appWidgetIds holds ids of multiple instance of your widget
         * meaning you are placing more than one widgets on your homescreen*/
        for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
            RemoteViews remoteViews = updateWidgetListView(context,
                    appWidgetIds[i]);
            remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imageView, getPendingSelfIntent(context, MyOnClick1));
            //remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.listViewWidget, getPendingSelfIntent(context, MyOnClick1));
            //remoteViews.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.listViewWidget, getPendingSelfIntent(context, "hai"));
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds[i], remoteViews);
        }
        super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
    }

    protected PendingIntent getPendingSelfIntent(Context context, String action) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, getClass());
        intent.setAction(action);
        return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

    }

    private RemoteViews updateWidgetListView(Context context, int appWidgetId) {

        //which layout to show on widget
        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.widget_layout);

        //RemoteViews Service needed to provide adapter for ListView
        Intent svcIntent = new Intent(context, WidgetService.class);
        //passing app widget id to that RemoteViews Service
        svcIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
        //setting a unique Uri to the intent
        //don't know its purpose to me right now
        svcIntent.setData(Uri.parse(svcIntent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
        //setting adapter to listview of the widget
        remoteViews.setRemoteAdapter(appWidgetId, R.id.listViewWidget,
                svcIntent);
        //setting an empty view in case of no data
        remoteViews.setEmptyView(R.id.listViewWidget, R.id.empty_view);
        remoteViews.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.listViewWidget, getPendingSelfIntent(context, "haiii"));
        return remoteViews;
    }


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
        Toast.makeText(context, "Button1_out side", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (MyOnClick1.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            // your onClick action is here
            Toast.makeText(context, "Button1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.w("Widget", "Clicked button1");


        }

    };


}
```

Comment: You should delete your commented out code, before posting here, as it isn't relevant.

Comment: ok abbath i will delete commented lines....